# Three.js mixer.time = n doesn't play on the n'th blender frame, nor does mixer.time=n/1000

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

In blender, my animation has a total length of 250ms.

[image]

But when I play my running animation to

```
mixer.time = 100/1000;
```

It only plays part of the animation.

```
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(cube);
      gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
      mixer.clipAction(clip).play();
             });
       });

...
     function seekAnimationTime(animMixer, timeInSeconds){
    animMixer.time=0;
    for(var i=0;i<animMixer._actions.length;i++){
      animMixer._actions[i].time=0;
    }
    animMixer.update(timeInSeconds)
  }
```

How to I make the animation run to a certain "frame" or time in blender units?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using

```
var duration = 0;
...
  mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(cube);
      gltf.animations.forEach((clip) => {
        duration = clip.duration;
      mixer.clipAction(clip).play();
             });
...
if(mixer!=null){
    var tar = 50; // percentage you want to play to
    var mul = duration*(tar/100)
        seekAnimationTime(mixer,elapsed*mul);//elapsed is a time scale running from 0 to 1
    }
```